# How long to I have to wait to re-enter US as a Canadian?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, canada

I am a Canadian citizen who has been doing work trade on a farm on Hawaii for 4.5 months come mid Oct. when I plan to return to Canada. I have also spent one month traveling in USA in Jan. of this year. Will I be able legally to return for another 4 mnths in Jan. 2019/how does the 6 month limit work?

Comment: Do you have a work permit for the work you're doing now?  Will you be doing work again when you go back?  There are two issues here, how long you're allowed to stay and whether you will be considered a US resident for tax purposes.

Comment: The "work trade" you're doing is [almost certainly legally considered "work"](https://de.usembassy.gov/unpaid-work-is-work-make-sure-you-have-the-correct-visa/) for immigration and legal purposes, because that's what it is. Did you get a J-1 or H-2A visa for this?

Comment: Edited the post pls re answer

Comment: @Samdunk You edited the post, but that doesn't change that you've been working.  It's not a value judgement—I don't care about that—, but it does impact the answer you're going to get. Spending months working in the US as a visitor, leaving, then coming back to do it again is the kind of thing immigration officers are trained to spot and stop. They're going to want to know what you've been doing and how you're supporting yourself. And an honest answer to that question is likely to get you denied entry to the US.

Comment: I rolled back the edit. If you're not honest with us about your situation, how can you expect an accurate answer?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I disagree with the rollback. An accurate answer to a question does not depend on whether the question honestly reflects the asker's actual circumstances.  I've also voted to reopen the question because the answer is quite clear as implied by Jim MacKenzie: there are two six-month limits and they work somewhat differently.

Comment: @phoog Obviously, we can attempt to answer any question that is asked. But that answer will not be useful to the asker if the question isn't actually about their situation. In particular, if the asker edits their question so that it misrepresents their situation, then the advice given to them is likely to be inappropriate and could cause them a lot of problems. Now, sure, it's their fault for misrepresenting themself but answering misleading questions is a waste of our time that could instead have been used to actually help somebody.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that is true.  Anyway I believe a useful answer can be offered to the question as it stands and I would include a few words about the effect of violating B-2 status by working (without offering an opinion about whether the asker has actually violated status, since there are surely relevant details missing from the question).  I've therefore voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @phoog OK. By the way, surely the workings of the six-month rule are already covered multiple times in other questions.

Comment: Okay. I understand that I have violated something by doing a work trade, but I want to know the answer to this situation in an event where I was just traveling and not work trading (considering I have been doing both)